# How do I add list column to infopath?

Tags: infopath

I have a custom list and I need to add a new column. Since the original form was customized using Infopath, will Infopath see the new column and just populate the column when clicking "Customize in Infopath" button?

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the list form with InfoPath, any changes in the data structure will be noticed. InfoPath will pop up a dialog saying that the structure has changed and whether or not you want to update the underlying list schema in InfoPath. After you click "yes" to that, you can then find the new columns in the field list and can add them to the canvas, or remove field controls that are no longer required because the column has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The form has been changed to include branching with collapsible sections. Any new columns I add would need to placed between existing fields. Would the new fields need to be created and connected to the new columns?

Comment: New columns will not be automatically added to the form. You need to insert them manually. Whether or not you need to add rows or columns depends on how your form is structured. You are in control.

Comment: If that answered your question, please click the tick mark next to the answer. That's how to say "thank you" here.